# Accessing ReferenceProperty values in a one to many relation from a referenced key in Appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am using AppEngine in Python and I have two Models using ndb  :

```
# Post model
class WikiPost(ndb.Model) :
    url  = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    content = ndb.TextProperty(required = True)
    date = ndb.DateProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

Second Model

```
class WikiPostVersion(ndb.Model) :
    r_post = ndb.KeyProperty(kind = WikiPost)
    content = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

How I can Access the values of the referenced key r_post of the model WikiPostVersion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`r_post` is a key, so you can just call `.get()` on it.

```
referenced_wikipost = my_wikipostversion_instance.r_post.get()
```